# From Service to Form suddenly doesn't work

Tags: c#, winforms

I made a Windows service in C# and kind of turned it into a Windows form now. (Don't worry I made the necessary changes to make it work)

So now all of the sudden some functions wont work. The form doesn't give me an error but it just doesn't do what it should be doing. Here is some **RELEVANT CODE**:

```
    private void Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.fileSystemWatcher1 = new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.fileSystemWatcher1)).BeginInit();
        fileSystemWatcher1.Path = source;
        fileSystemWatcher1.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(fileSystemWatcher1_Created);
        fileSystemWatcher1.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(fileSystemWatcher1_Changed);
        fileSystemWatcher1.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(fileSystemWatcher1_Deleted);
        fileSystemWatcher1.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(fileSystemWatcher1_Renamed);

        this.fileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        this.fileSystemWatcher1.IncludeSubdirectories = true;
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.fileSystemWatcher1)).EndInit();
        logger("Service started " + DateTime.Now);
    }

    public static void logger(String entry)
    {
        String logfile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[@"log"];
        if (File.Exists(@logfile))
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@logfile, true))
            {
                file.WriteLine(entry);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            string[] lines = { entry };
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@logfile, lines);
        }
    }

//some more functions as the logger.


private void fileSystemWatcher1_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {

            cut_copy = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[@"cutter"];
            logger("File created> " + e.FullPath + " -Date:" + DateTime.Now);
            filepath = Path.Combine(source, e.Name);
            name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filepath);
            extension = Path.GetExtension(e.FullPath);
            size = e.Name.Length;

            strSelectCmd = "INSERT INTO" + tablepostgresql + " (" + column1 + "," + column2 + "," + column3 + "," + column4 + ") VALUES('" + name + "','" + size + "',now(),'" + extension + "')";
            readquery = "select * from " + tablemysql + " where name='" + name + "'";
            Mysql();
            postgresql();
            Record();

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename) == false)
            {
                if (Directory.Exists(e.FullPath))
                {
                    copyfolder();
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(target);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (WaitForFileAvailable(e.FullPath, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)))
                    {
                        var file = Path.Combine(source, e.Name);
                        var copy_file = Path.Combine(target, e.Name);
                        var destination = Path.Combine(target, Path.ChangeExtension(source, Path.GetExtension(source)));


                            if (File.Exists(file))// Check to see if the file exists. 
                            {                     //If it does delete the file in the target and copy the one from the source to the target.
                                File.Delete(copy_file);

                            }
                            File.Copy(e.FullPath, copy_file);

                    }
                    else // The file failed to become available within 10 seconds.
                    {
                        logger("Copy has failed reason: File is being used by another program");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                query = "INSERT INTO " + tablemysql + " (name,size,last_edit,extension) VALUES('" + name + "','" + size + "',now(),'" + extension + "')";
                Mysql();
            }
            variable_reset();

    }
```

My problem is, all the functions in the button are working, like the `logger("Service started " + DateTime.Now);`, but the `fileSystemWatcher1_Created`doesn't work(**it does nothing**). 
This might just be a very stupid question, but I am very confused and it's been a pretty long time since i've worked on this.

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a good description of your problem. What doesn't work? Is the fileSystemWatcher1_Deleted method called or not? "it just doesn't do what it should be doing" => what it is supposed to do?

Comment: @CyrilGandon Sorry I mean it's just doing nothing. It's not like I get an error or something or doing things he shouldn't do, but it just does nothing.

Comment: Have you placed a breakpoint in that section of code? Are you setting the `pause` variable to true so that if block actually executes?

Comment: Explain "does not work". Debug. Does your `Start_Click` run to completion? Does the `fileSystemWatcher1_Deleted` get called? What is the value of `pause`?

Comment: I thought you said you had made all of the necessary changes to make it work? Also are you sure you want to be checking `if (pause)` and not `if (!pause)`?

Comment: @MichaelJ.Gray I even tried it without the pause boolean and it still did nothing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Forms with FileSystemWatcher not launching a child form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6695944/windows-forms-with-filesystemwatcher-not-launching-a-child-form)

Comment: @CodeCaster with "does not work" I mean it does nothing. It also doesn't give me an error or anything else. It's not even doing stuff it shouldn't do. Just nothing.

Comment: It is impossible for it to do _nothing_. Debug it.

Comment: @ChrisLively yes well I also have filesystemwatcher1_created. That is the one that doesn't go through it at debugging atm all of the sudden. I'll post that code.

Comment: @CodeCaster I debugged it. I got filesystemwatcher_created as well and it wont go through that. All of the sudden it DOES go through the deleted. See my new code. Also I just erased the boolean and the start_click does run completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the property `SynchronizingObject` of `FileSystemWatcher` to your form:

```
this.fileSystemWatcher1 = new System.IO.FileSystemWatcher();
this.fileSystemWatcher1.SynchronizingObject = this;
```

[FileSystemWatcher.SynchronizingObject Property@MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.synchronizingobject.aspx)

> When the Changed, Created, Deleted, and Renamed events are handled by
>   a visual Windows Forms component, such as a Button, accessing the
>   component through the system thread pool **might not work, or may result
>   in an exception**. Avoid this by setting SynchronizingObject to a
>   Windows Forms component, which causes the methods that handle the
>   Changed, Created, Deleted, and Renamed events to be called on the same
>   thread on which the component was created.

Side note : the property `SynchronizingObject` is `ISynchronizeInvoke`, and [`Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx) is `ISynchronizeInvoke` too.

Comment: Ok this might have helped me, but still not fixing my main problem. Still giving you the answer cause I cant seem to get the answer here anyway